# Was Matt Dillon the first choice for Carl?

Tags: casting, you-me-and-dupree

For the movie 'You, Me, and Dupree', was Matt Dillon the first choice to play Carl?

Reason I ask:

- Owen Wilson as Dupree and Kate Hudson as Molly make the movie.
- But I wonder if the person in charge of casting evaluated Matt Dillon for his chemistry with Owen Wilson and Kate Hudson, and if so, were other actors considered.